# Is there any class called 'barone' in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, class

When I am learning Bootstrap, I saw a class "barone" in a tutorial, but they didn't explained the use of that class. This is the site
http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/tutorial.php

Is there any class in Bootstrap in this name?

Thanks

Comment: Read the docs. Grep the source. Google it. Take it out and see what changes. Look at the style inspector to see if it's bringing in any rules.

Comment: No, there is no such class. Some custom one.

Comment: Press Ctrl + F in your visual studio. If it's within a bootstrap css file, it's more than likely part of it. Otherwise it'll more than likely be custom. Either way, it'll be there or won't be.

Comment: Yes I googled it and also searched in the Bootstrap doc. I am new to coding so I asked. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know, classes are used to group elements together. As you can see in the following example:

```css
p.exampleID3 { background-color: #013370; color: white;}
```

```html
<p class='exampleID3'>These paragraphs all have the same styling applied to them and we used classes because we wanted to reuse our styling!</p>
<p class='exampleID3'>These paragraphs all have the same styling applied to them and we used classes because we wanted to reuse our styling!</p>
<p class='exampleID3'>These paragraphs all have the same styling applied to them and we used classes because we wanted to reuse our styling!</p>
```

The class is exampleID3 and is present in the css file. In your case "row barone" should be somewhere in the css file, but it's not shown in the tutorial and you don't really know what it contains.